# retain improper name with indexing

Tags: r

I have need to name columns of a data.frame with duplicate names.  inside of `data.frame` you can use `check.names = FALSE` to do the naughty name deed.  But if you index this then you lose the naughty names when indexing.  I want to retain those names.  So beloe is an example and the output I get and I'd like to get:

```
x <- data.frame(b= 4:6, a =6:8, a =6:8, check.names = FALSE)
x[, -1]
```

I get:

```
  a a.1
1 6   6
2 7   7
3 8   8
```

I'd like:

```
  a a
1 6 6
2 7 7
3 8 8
```

Comment: We look forward to your contributed `safe.data.frame()` function :)

Comment: @joran what do you mean?  This data frame is much larger with many columns and multiple duplicated names.  I'm taking pieces of the data frame operating on them/combining them and putting things back together.

Comment: @Dason I made the fix you are correct

Comment: @TylerRinker Sorry, my eyes are just a bit bleary. Substituted rows/columns.

Comment: @joran I changed the column numbers so they don't match row names.  You're right that's a bit difficult to keep things straight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
subdf <- function(df, ii) {
    do.call("data.frame", c(as.list(df)[ii], check.names=FALSE))
}

subdf(x, -1)
#   a a
# 1 6 6
# 2 7 7
# 3 8 8

subdf(x, 2:3)
#   a a
# 1 6 6
# 2 7 7
# 3 8 8
```

Comment: I think this is closest to the mission I had of not renaming columns.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an ugly solution

```
> tmp <- data.frame(b=4:6, a=6:8, a=6:8, check.names=FALSE)
> setNames(tmp[, -1], names(tmp)[-1])
  a a
1 6 6
2 7 7
3 8 8
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the code for `[.data.frame` gives this as part of the code

```
if (anyDuplicated(cols)) 
    names(y) <- make.unique(cols)
```

and I couldn't see anything in the code that would allow one to skip that check.  So it looks like we'll just have to write our own function.  It's not very safe though and I'm sure a much better version could be created...

```
dropCols <- function(x, cols){
  nm <- colnames(x)
  x <- x[, -cols]
  colnames(x) <- nm[-cols]
  x
}

x <- data.frame(b= 4:6, a =6:8, a =6:8, check.names = FALSE)
#x[, -1]
dropCols(x, 1)
#  a a
#1 6 6
#2 7 7
#3 8 8
```

Answer (score 2):

per dirks tongue in cheek comment:

```
safe.data.frame <- function(dat, index) {
    colnam <-colnames(dat)[index]
    dat2 <- dat[, index]
    colnames(dat2) <- colnam
    dat2
}
safe.data.frame(x, -1)
```

I was hoping for something better :)

Comment: "My work is done here".  Have to admit that Josh OB's is nicer though :)